# How create new instance of a model in relation many to many?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I try to create a furniture object, which is in relation by a has_many_and_belongs_to with stores, this is my model:

```
class Furniture < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :area, :description, :name, :size

  has_and_belongs_to_many :stores
end
```

My problem is that I don't know how create a new furniture, because i try to associate furniture with one or more store with check box, but I obtain this error: `undefined method merge for #<Store:0x007ff16ae27e40>`.

These are my view with form and my controller with new and create action:

**View**:

```
<%= form_for @furniture do |f| %>
        <%= f.label :name %>
        <%= f.text_field :name %> <br><br>

        <%= f.label :description %>
        <%= f.text_field :description %> <br><br>

        <%= f.label :size %>
        <%= f.text_field :size %> <br><br>

        <% @store.each do |store| %>
            <div>
                <%= f.check_box :stores, store %>
                <%= store.name %>
            </div>
        <% end %>

        <%= f.submit %>

    <% end %>
```

**Controller**:

```
    def new
        @furniture = Furniture.new
        @store = Store.order('name ASC')
      end

      def create
        @furniture = Furniture.create(params[:furniture])
        redirect_to admins_path
      end
```

How can I solve it?? Have you some suggestion to create a new object with this relation ship??

Thank you very much

**EDIT**:
I have a join table between furniture and store

Comment: stacktrace please. also, not sure I understand your question, but you can use `@furniture.stores.build` to create a new instance of `Store`.

Comment: I want create a new Furniture, and I take by form all value for it, than I want assign some store to the new furniture too. I select some store with chcekbox, but I can't assign the store to furniture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The has_and_belongs_to association adds a method `collection_singular_ids=` that for the current case will be `@furniture.store_ids=`. According to the docs

> The collection_singular_ids= method makes the collection contain only the objects identified by the supplied primary key values, by adding and deleting as appropriate.

So, you can use this idea to add the stores to your furniture. Replace

```
<% @store.each do |store| %>
  <div>
    <%= f.check_box :stores, store %>
    <%= store.name %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

with

```
<% @store.each do |store| %>
  <div>
    <%= f.check_box :store_ids, {:multiple => true}, store.id, nil %>
    <%= store.name %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I tried but now I have this error:`Cant mass-assign protected attributes: store_ids`.

Comment: I added `:store_ids` to `accessible_attr` in furniture controller to solve the last error, and now it works.. thanks